# How to restrict minimum form's width in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How do I restrict a minimum form's width in FireMonkey? It used to be so easy in VCL - it just had Max and Min constraints in forms properties.

Comment: tondog - would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

#### Note for future readers:

This will only work for versions below XE3 because the `Fmx::Platform::TPlatform` class was removed in XE3. Thanks to @Alain Thiffault for pointing it out in the comments.

#### Original Post:

Here's a more complicated (but more elegant) alternative solution, defining an entirely custom Form class from which you can inherit your own...

```
unit FMX.ConstrainedForm;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Types, System.UITypes, FMX.Forms, FMX.Platform, FMX.Types;

type
  TFormConstraints = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMaxHeight: Integer;
    FMaxLeft: Integer;
    FMaxWidth: Integer;
    FMaxTop: Integer;
    FMinHeight: Integer;
    FMinLeft: Integer;
    FMinWidth: Integer;
    FMinTop: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
  published
    property MaxHeight: Integer read FMaxHeight write FMaxHeight default 0;
    property MaxLeft: Integer read FMaxLeft write FMaxLeft default 0;
    property MaxWidth: Integer read FMaxWidth write FMaxWidth default 0;
    property MaxTop: Integer read FMaxTop write FMaxTop default 0;
    property MinHeight: Integer read FMinHeight write FMinHeight default 0;
    property MinLeft: Integer read FMinLeft write FMinLeft default 0;
    property MinWidth: Integer read FMinWidth write FMinWidth default 0;
    property MinTop: Integer read FMinTop write FMinTop default 0;
  end;

  TConstrainedForm = class(TCustomForm)
  private
    FConstraints: TFormConstraints;
  protected
    procedure StartWindowResize; override;
    procedure StartWindowDrag; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property Constraints: TFormConstraints read FConstraints write FConstraints;
    property BiDiMode;
    property Caption;
    property Cursor default crDefault;
    property BorderStyle default TFmxFormBorderStyle.bsSizeable;
    property BorderIcons default [TBorderIcon.biSystemMenu, TBorderIcon.biMinimize, TBorderIcon.biMaximize];
    property ClientHeight;
    property ClientWidth;
    property Left;
    property Top;
    property Margins;
    property Position default TFormPosition.poDefaultPosOnly;
    property Width;
    property Height;
    property ShowActivated default True;
    property StaysOpen default True;
    property Transparency;
    property TopMost default False;
    property Visible;
    property WindowState default TWindowState.wsNormal;
    property OnCreate;
    property OnDestroy;
    property OnClose;
    property OnCloseQuery;
    property OnActivate;
    property OnDeactivate;
    property OnResize;
    property Fill;
    property StyleBook;
    property ActiveControl;
    property StyleLookup;
    property OnPaint;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{ TFormConstraints }

constructor TFormConstraints.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FMaxHeight := 0;
  FMaxLeft := 0;
  FMaxWidth := 0;
  FMaxTop := 0;
  FMinHeight := 0;
  FMinLeft := 0;
  FMinWidth := 0;
  FMinTop := 0;
end;

{ TConstrainedForm }

constructor TConstrainedForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FConstraints := TFormConstraints.Create;
  inherited;
end;

destructor TConstrainedForm.Destroy;
begin
  FConstraints.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TConstrainedForm.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if (FConstraints.FMinWidth > 0) and (AWidth < FConstraints.FMinWidth) then
    AWidth := FConstraints.FMinWidth;

  if (FConstraints.FMaxWidth > 0) and (AWidth > FConstraints.FMaxWidth) then
    AWidth := FConstraints.FMaxWidth;

  if (FConstraints.FMinHeight > 0) and (AHeight < FConstraints.FMinHeight) then
    AHeight := FConstraints.FMinHeight;

  if (FConstraints.FMaxHeight > 0) and (AHeight > FConstraints.FMaxHeight) then
    AHeight := FConstraints.FMaxHeight;

  if (FConstraints.FMinLeft > 0) and (ALeft < FConstraints.FMinLeft) then
    ALeft := FConstraints.FMinLeft;

  if (FConstraints.FMaxLeft > 0) and (ALeft > FConstraints.FMaxLeft) then
    ALeft := FConstraints.FMaxLeft;

  if (FConstraints.FMinTop > 0) and (ATop < FConstraints.FMinTop) then
    ATop := FConstraints.FMinTop;

  if (FConstraints.FMaxTop > 0) and (ATop > FConstraints.FMaxTop) then
    ATop := FConstraints.FMaxTop;

  Platform.SetWindowRect(Self, RectF(ALeft, ATop, ALeft + AWidth, ATop + AHeight));
  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

procedure TConstrainedForm.StartWindowDrag;
begin
  inherited;

end;

procedure TConstrainedForm.StartWindowResize;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterClass(TConstrainedForm);
end;

end.
```

Store this file as FMX.ConstrainedForm.pas, add it to your Form's "uses" section, and modify the declaration of your form so that instead of:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
```

it says:

```
TForm1 = class(TConstrainedForm)
```

Due to the lack of a custom designed (at this point anyway, this is a "quick solution"), you then need to hook your form's OnCreate event as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Constraints.MinWidth := 400;
  Constraints.MinHeight := 400;
end;
```

Now this form will not allow the user to set its width or height below 400!

Again, without making some substancial changes to the FireMonkey Platform itself, this is the best you're going to get for now!

Comment: Yikes...!  Is that what it takes these days to just set a form minimum??? It used to just be one field in Delphi...

Comment: Could you tell me, where would I put the above code? In a new unit? Forgive my ignorance. I'm not very knowledgable about anything that leaves the default Delphi form. Can you somehow work this code into the default Form1

Comment: Yes, you'd place this ideally in a separate unit with the name "FMX.ConstrainedForm.pas", which is then linked to your project!

Comment: I would suggest using InRange(FConstraints.FMinTop, 0, ATop) to make code a bit shorter, so not to scare people off

Comment: @Krom a good suggestion... will confess I was unaware of the InRange function! I may edit this solution soon to reflect this. Working on a much more complicated solution for another question atm, though.

Comment: Realize this is an old post but since I ended up here with google, note that Fmx::Platform::TPlatform class was removed in XE3.  See this link for more details: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117749

Answer (score 5):

Place this on the form's "OnResize" event, replace the values as appropriate.
Granted, not the best solution in the world, but it'll get you by until the properties are reintroduced!

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Width < 400 then
    Width := 400;
  if Height < 400 then
    Height := 400;
end;
```

The above code is easy enough to change for any combination of maximums or minimums, so have fun!

Comment: Actually, I'm going to do you one better! I'll create for you a custom TForm class you can use wherever you like, which provides the Constraints properties for you :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the above "FormResize" code is, it results in strange form behavior and animation "artifacts" -- e.g. flicker of the form and crap on the screen.

Comment: I would use this. It's not perfect, but it will get you by for now. Also, another thing to get you by is just to let the user set the form as small as they want. Most applications don't restrict the user on this one.

Answer (score 5):

LaKraven, simulate a mouseUp event to get rid of that flickering.

```
if (Width > maxWidth) then
begin
  Width := maxWidth;
  Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: This is a great and simple solution. It works for me. Since the form does not flicker on Mac, it is good enough that it only works on Windows.

Comment: Ah, it releases user mouse when it make window smaller that constrains, to not allow drag size grip further. If user want to move this size in back direction, it will must move mouse back to grip and press it again. It's bad decision, but may be better than flickering...

Answer (score 5):

Just found out `TForm` has a [`Constraints`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Forms.TForm.Constraints) property in Delphi 11.

[image: demo]

Works perfectly for me without flickering.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally for LaKraven's answer about FormResize based solution, use ClientWidth and ClientHeight instead of Width and Height to prevent stretching of the form.

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if ClientWidth < 400 then
        ClientWidth := 400;
    if ClientHeight < 400 then
        ClientHeight := 400;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an updated version to Sunec's answer, to get rid of flickering.

According to MSDN Mouse_Event has been superseded and SendInput should be used instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event

```
uses WinApi.Windows;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  LInput: TInput;
begin
  if ClientHeight < MIN_HEIGHT then
  begin
    ClientHeight := MIN_HEIGHT;
    FillMemory(@LInput, SizeOf(LInput), 0);
    LInput.Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    LInput.mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, LInput, SizeOf(LInput));
  end;
  if ClientWidth < MIN_WIDTH then
  begin
    ClientWidth := MIN_WIDTH;
    FillMemory(@LInput, SizeOf(LInput), 0);
    LInput.Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    LInput.mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, LInput, SizeOf(LInput));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just a note that when I use ClientWidth / ClientHeight the value appears to be wrong on some Windows machines if the form's Transparency property is enabled. ClientWidth appears to be 0, resulting in the window getting reduced to the smallest size when first shown. Using Width and Height instead is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

To summery the above for a useful answer just use code below:

```
Uses Winapi.Windows;

Procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
Begin
 If ClientWidth < 400 Then
    Begin
      ClientWidth := 400;
      Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    End;

  If ClientHeight < 400 Then
    Begin
      ClientHeight := 400;
      Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    End;
End;
```